# Kafka to Spark streaming using Pyspark error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to get data into spark from a kafka topic, but I am not able to do that.
I have tried the tutorials whose link is shared, but at last I am getting error.
I have added all the required jar files too (location:- usr/local/spark/jars).
Please let me know what could be wrong.
Also I would like to know how this can be done with scala programming.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#deploying-applications

https://medium.com/@kass09/spark-streaming-kafka-in-python-a-test-on-local-machine-edd47814746
[image]

Trying out this spark streaming command I got the error.

" bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.1.1 examples/src/main/python/streaming/direct_kafka_wordcount.py"

I got a jupyter error so I tried folowing command to solve it, but still the error remains same
"pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter"

Comment: Are you trying to submit a jupyter notebook? That is not going to work (as far as I know). You can submit .py files or create a spark context in your jupyter notebook.

Comment: Please share sudo code and steps on how you are running your program to help better, this seems be the error due to missing library or class path error.

Comment: The second link that I have shared of medium.com, I have exactly done the same steps, but I am getting error while running the python code. Also I have followed the simple wordcount example from link 1(spark.apache.org)  @SureshChaganti

Comment: @SureshChaganti please check the images I have added in my question.

Comment: @SureshChaganti  Hi, I have updated my question after trying few solutions, so now I am getting this error. Kindly check it and help me get through this.

Comment: @NishadNazar sorry for the late reply, Not sure how you are trying to execute. just to make sure, your Kafka and Spark setup is correct. please run your test producer and consumer for Kafka and there and there are many examples under this folder `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.0/libexec/examples/src/main/python/` please run one of them to verify your setup.

Comment: and just fyi spark streaming kafka dependency comes with spark itself. just refer this example. you will get an idea `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.0/libexec/examples/src/main/python/streaming/direct_kafka_wordcount.py

Comment: @SureshChaganti Yes, Kafka and Spark is installed fine. I have tested producing kafka messages and consuming it, and also I have tested Spark, word count.py file on the spark console.

Comment: @SureshChaganti , I will give u a headsup on my versions, Becuase I think its some sort of version mismatch, I have JAva 8 Oracle; jdk1.8.0_201 installed, and have linked spark using https://medium.com/@brajendragouda/installing-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-pyspark-on-juputer-ca8e40e8e655. Installed Spark2.1.1, Scala 2.11 and Kafka according to it, and Apache streaming kafka 0-8. And now I run :  spark-submit --jars jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.1.1.jar examples/src/main/python/streaming/direct_kafka_wordcount.py localhost:9092 test

Comment: @SureshChaganti And after all this, I still get: py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext. Error. I also tried : spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.11:2.1.1 examples/src/main/python/streaming/direct_kafka_wordcount.py localhost:9092 test
, but not working

Comment: FYI, Im trying in python. I duno why this is hauting me so much, WE can sync in chat also, I need a solution buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Spark and Kafka integration in Scala

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent


object sparkStreaming_Kafka {

  @transient lazy val log = org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger("sparkStreaming_Kafka")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    log.debug("added the messages ****** ---->>>")

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("my_App" )
      .getOrCreate()

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(2)) // the polling frequency is 2 seconds, can be modified based on the BM requirements.
    log.debug("Before starting the Stream -->>")
    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String]
      (Array.apply("my_topic"), getKafkaParams())).map(record => record.value)

    stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      try {
        if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
          rdd.foreach(x => postData(x))
        }
      } catch {
        case t: Throwable =>
          t.printStackTrace() // TODO: handle error
          log.error("Exception occured while processing the data exception is {}", t.getCause)
      }
    }

    ssc.start()
    log.debug("started now-->> " + compat.Platform.currentTime)
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

  def getKafkaParams(): Map[String, Object] = {
    Map[String, Object]("bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "group_id",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (true: java.lang.Boolean)) 
  }


  def postData(event: String): Unit = {
    log.info("before KinesisSink.process call ==>>"+event)

    print(event)  // use the event as per the requirement

  }
}
```

Comment: Where do I run this scala code? In spark-shell scala terminal?

Comment: Hi @NishadNazar please create a maven project around it.

Comment: HI, I think I have done a bit right this time. Here, we have the code, but I guess some dependency error. [error] 19/06/27 11:24:56 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
 this is what I get immediately after i SBT RUN the project.

Comment: Hi @SureshChaganti ?

Comment: Hi @Suresh Chaganti just a small question, is there a way to send data from kafka to any database excluding spark. Please let me know about this.

Comment: we can use plain java consumer to read and post to database, @NishadNazar

Comment: sorry not able to find the time to reproduce above issue

Comment: No prbs @Suresh Chaganti, Could you tell me, Is it possible to store Kafka data to Postgresql or Spark data to Postgresql.